# Dle-Billing DataLife Engine

Tags: javascript, php

In time to call the ajax function on the site I receive the next problem:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at BillingNews.Declension (fixednews.js:97:23)
    at BillingNews.Days (fixednews.js:65:90)
    at Object.success (fixednews.js:39:16)
    at i (index.php?g=general&v=1bz3s:2:27151)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (index.php?g=general&v=1bz3s:2:27914)
    at z (index.php?g=general&v=1bz3s:4:12059)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (index.php?g=general&v=1bz3s:4:15619)
```

This 'split' has next function:

```
this.Declension = function( number, currency )
    {
        currency = currency.split(',');
        cases = [2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2];

        return ' ' + currency[ (number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 : cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5] ];
    }
```

I using PHP 8.1, in PHP 7.4 all is working fine.

I make next change of split:

```
if (currency !== null && currency !== undefined && currency !== "") {
    currency = currency.split(',');
} else {
    console.error("currency is null or empty");
}
```

but is not working